# python - no module named 'requests' error

Tags: python

I'm completely new to python and have just installed python 3.6.1. I'm trying to run a script that downloads the stock tickers from yahoo, which I've downloaded from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Yahoo-ticker-downloader

But when I run it I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\YahooTickerDownloader.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ytd.downloader.StockDownloader import StockDownloader
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\ytd\downloader\StockDownloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..SymbolDownloader import SymbolDownloader
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\Yahoo-ticker-downloader-1.0.0\ytd\SymbolDownloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

Can anyone help me with solving this issue?

Comment: Try pip install requests

Comment: Doc: [Installing Python Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

The module [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/) is an external module you need to install first. This may help:

```
pip3.6 install requests
```

It's a shell command to install the latest requests module for Python 3.6. In some machines, you may need to replace `pip3.6` with `pip`. You can check the Python external module installation documentation in [this page](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html).

Comment: it is more explicit to write `python3.6 -m pip install ...` instead

Comment: You are right (I tend to use only one Python3 version). Thanks. I have updated my reply.

Comment: Hi, @The_Wiz! If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can install [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/):

```
pip install requests
```